# Sql group by month and year with rollup

Tags: sql, group-by, sql-server-2012

I'm using the code below to list a calculated output for each month of the  financial year (Apr14 to Mar15):

```
select 
datename(month,arvd) Mth,
year(arvd) Yr,
count(submissionid) n,
max(HES/12) HES,
cast(count(submissionid) / max(HES/12)*100 as decimal(5,2)) DataCompleteness

from PRIcache p
left join (select distinct hsite, HES from hsite where hyear=2013) hs on
hs.hSite = p.site

where siteid=8 and arvd between '20140401' and '20150331'

group by datename(month,arvd), datepart(month,arvd), year(arvd)
order by year(arvd), datepart(month,arvd)
```

The code is running to give me the monthly figures in the format below:

Mth                            Yr          n           HES                    DataCompleteness

---

April                          2014        49          48.5                   101.03

I want to add a summary total at the bottom, I'd usually do this with rollup but because I am grouping on more than one field it adds duplicates rows to my results.

Is there a way around this? I'm using SQL Server MS 2012

Thanks

Comment: Don't use `BETWEEN` with contiguous-range types, [like date/time/timestamps](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) (especially in SQL Server).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group by `GROUPING SETS` with empty grouping:

```
...
Group by Grouping Sets((datename(month,arvd), datepart(month,arvd), year(arvd)), ())
order by year(arvd), datepart(month,arvd)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the advice on Grouping Sets, I've combined them with a subquery to get the output I needed:

```
Select  isnull(Mth,'Total') Mth,
    isnull(Yr,'9999') Yr,
    sum(n) ActualSubmissions,
    sum(HES) ExpectedSubmissions,
    cast(avg(DataCompleteness) as decimal(5,2)) DataCompleteness

from 

    (select     datename(month,arvd) Mth,
                Month(arvd) MthSort,
                Year(arvd) Yr,
                count(submissionid) n,
                HES/12 HES,
                cast(count(submissionID)/(HES/12) as decimal(5,2))   DataCompleteness
     from PRIcache p
        left join hSite on p.site=hSite and hyear=2013
     where siteid=8888 and arvd between '20140401' and '20150330'
     group by datename(month,arvd), Month(arvd), year(arvd), HES) #datacomp 


group by Grouping sets ((Mth,Yr,MthSort),())

order by Yr, MthSort
```